# Taking the limit of the derivatives of the Beta function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I tried using `Limit[D[Beta[a,b],{a,1},{b,1}],{a -> 1},{b -> 1}]` and `Limit[D[Beta[a,b],{a,1},{b,1}],{a , 1},{b , 1}]`
but it doesnt seem to work, why?

Comment: `Limit[D[Beta[a, b], {a, 1}, {b, 1}], {a, b} -> {1, 1}]`

Comment: Or, `Limit[D[Beta[a, b], {a, 1}, {b, 1}], {a -> 1, b -> 1}]`

Comment: Limit[D[Beta[a,b],{a,1},{b,1}], a -> 1,b -> 1] seems to work as fine too, thanks guys :)

Comment: You don't need the limit, since derivative is smooth at {1,1}, Just do `Derivative[1, 1][Beta][1, 1] ` to get `2 - \[Pi]^2/6 `